# In Iron Man 1, what did the computer in the cave do?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man, iron-man-2008

In the first Iron Man film, as Tony is about to escape in the first Iron Man suit, he has Yensil run commands on a computer in the cave.  What was the point of this?  What was the computer doing?  It seemed to be a pretty simple mechanical suit, so there clearly wasn't a "Jarvis" equivalent.  The suit wasn't computer controlled at all.  So, what purpose, exactly, did the computer serve?

[image]

Comment: What in the world makes you think it was "a pretty simple mechanical suit" with no onboard processing?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

How do you know the suit wasn't computer controlled?

The software assists in moving the armor. As Tony moves his arm, the suit needs to mechanically move the arm. Otherwise Tony would need to be able to walk around in a 200+ pound suit-+. You see this when his leg seizes up, and he isn't able to walk until he deactivates the servos on the leg.

[image]

It seems to me the code behind the progress bar is code that actually displays the progress bar.

-+ basing this off the real life suit XOS 2 suit built by [Raytheon-Sarcos](http://www.ksl.com/?nid=148&sid=12599362)

Comment: A quick google search tells me that code is pieced together from [firmdl3.c](http://idun.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/reflex/cgi/reflex-trac.fcgi/browser/trunk/platform/RCX/tools/firmdl3.c?rev=462) *(eg. lines 772 and 724)*, a firmware downloader for Lego Mindstorms.  It looks like they also added the words *"Long Message!"* into a few random places, presumably to make the code look longer.

Comment: A slow Google search reveals nothing, except that your internet might be down.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft - now we need a lawyer to decide if this is a copyright violation and they have to release Iron Man as Open Source to comply with MPL. :)

Comment: @zch The MPL is [non-viral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viral_license), so they would not be required to open-source Iron Man.  They may, however, be required to send you the code displayed on that screen if you requested it.

Comment: But you think Tony would have made a Rasberry Pi with its many applications and its Open Source content to substitute the awesome Jarvis. Sauter some extra SD readers for memory expansion and you got yourself a robot!

Comment: Also of worth is this from IMDb's Trivia page: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0371746/trivia?item=tr0748556